# Set Local Storage Item to Value of 'span' Tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

Essentially, I want to grab the value of an item stored locally and set that to the value of a 'span' tag nested in an 'h2' tag. You will notice from my code that the number locally stored increases by one every time the 'test' button is clicked. My code properly stores the number, but does not update the 'span' tag - even when I reload the page. Also, I am using Bootstrap which accounts for bits of the code :)

**HTML:**

```
<h2 class="text-center"><span class="single" id="memberCount"></span>    
Members and Counting.</h2>

<button class="btn btn-success" id="test">Test</button>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var increment = 23;

$("#memberCount").val(localStorage.getItem("memberCount"));

$("#test").on('click', function () {

     increment++;

     if (typeof localStorage !== 'undefined') {

         localStorage.setItem("memberCount", increment);

     }else {

        alert("Your browser is out of date. Please update.");

     }

});
```

Thanks so much for all your help!

Comment: instead of `$("#memberCount").val(...` use `$("#memberCount").text(...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `.text()` or `.html()`, cause `.val()` is meant for form action elements.

```
var increment = localStorage.memberCount || 23;
$("#memberCount").text( increment );

$("#test").on('click', function () {
  localStorage.memberCount = ++increment;
  $("#memberCount").text( increment );
});
```

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/xomele/3/edit?html,css,js,console,output)***

P.S: don't be afraid of `localStorage` http://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage

Comment: Is there any way to store this data on the server using Javascript? The code worked, but I want it to update the value of the 'span' tag permanently. Will I have to use a server side language, or could I use console.log() or something similar?

Comment: Yes, you must use some server-side in that case. PHP? Node.js? Or if you want to do it really fast you can take a look at (Google's) Firebase.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Moral of the story: Use .html(), or even better .text() on a span tag, not val()

```
'use strict';

var increment = 23;


function setMemberCount(){
    $("#memberCount").html(localStorage.getItem("memberCount"));
}


function doWork(){
     increment++;
     if (typeof localStorage !== 'undefined') {
         localStorage.setItem("memberCount", increment);
          setMemberCount();
     }
    else alert("Your browser is out of date. Please update.");
}

$("#test").on('click', doWork);
```

http://codepen.io/nicholasabrams/pen/pydRaB